# Passing List of custom object to modal popup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I want to make the content of the bootstrap modal popup in a separate view file, and call the corresponding action method `GET Action` related to the view file before render the view, and pass a list of custom object to the view via the action method.

**The modal:**

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="assign_device" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
               <h4 class="modal-title">Assign Device</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Device list here
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

the above `modal` popup must appears in the current page(like `index.cshtml`) when I click a button.

Comment: Add your calling code to this view as well ?

Comment: @Ahmar let's say there is a `index.cshtml` view, in this view there is a button, when click the button I want the modal to popup (with data passed to it)

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an action method.

```
public PartialViewResult GetDevice()
{
   var devices= FetchDevices();

   return PartialView("viewName", devices);
}
```

Your view will be like this

```
@model DeviceModelNamespace
<div class="modal fade" id="assign_device" tabindex="-1">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Assign Device</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        foreach over devicemodel
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and call it in otherview like this

```
@Html.Partial("viewName")
```

and use it in bootstrap model

```
<script>
    $("#load-partial").on('click', function () {
        console.log('click');
        //setup modal
        $('#dynamic-modal').modal({
            keyboard: false,
            remote: '/controllername/partialviewname'
        }).show();
    });
    $('#dynamic-modal').on('showen.bs.modal', function(e) {
        console.log('shown');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: where to put the `@Html.partial("viewname")` ? if I have a view `index.cshtml` that contains a button, when i click the button the popup modal must show with data passed to it.